# How to make node shadow in force directed graph D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i want to make shadow of the node in d3.js and this is my code.

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(dataset.nodes)
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr("r", 10)
                        .style("box-shadow", "0 0 20px rgb(15, 153, 217)")
                        .style("fill", function(d){
                            return d.color;
                        })
                        .call(node_drag);
```

I have add box-shadow to node style but it nothing happen.

Comment: @Guillermo Garcia Thank you very much, that is what i looking for.